# Reflecting changes made in Banana Dashboard?

Tags: solr, banana

I'm getting issues with getting results on Banana Dashboard. I've changed the **default query *:*** of the **query panel** to ' ' in there **module.js** file such that if I load an index on Banana, it will not give me the list of documents immediately.
     I've cleared the cache on the browser and also restarted the solr but that didn't work out.Is there any way we could reflect changes we have made in banana on to the UI?

Thanks